# Generalization of Inverse Function Theorem to noncompact submanifolds

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*, they give as an exercise (#1.8.14) to prove the following generalization of the Inverse Function Theorem:

> Use a partition-of-unity technique to prove a noncompact version of
>   [the Inverse Function Theorem]. Suppose that the derivative of $f: X
>  \to Y$ is an isomorphism whenever $x$ lies in the submanifold $Z
>  \subset X$, and assume that $f$ maps $Z$ diffeomorphically onto
>   $f(Z)$. Prove that $f$ maps a neighborhood of $Z$ diffeomorphically
>   onto a neighborhood of $f(Z)$.

There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393932/showing-a-diffeomorphism-extends-to-the-neighborhood-of-a-submanifold/394074#comment2878604_394074), but there is one thing I don't understand. I'll summarize the answer. Take a local diffeomorphism neighborhood $U_z$ around each $z \in Z$, giving an open cover $f(U_z)$ of $f(Z)$. Take a locally finite refinement $V_i$. Let $g_i$ be the local inverses defined on each $V_i$. For each $V_i \cap V_j$, let $W_{ij}:= \{y \in V_i \cap V_j: g_i(y) \neq g_j(y)\}$. The sets $\overline{W_{ij}}$ are locally finite, so their union is closed, so $(\cup_z f(U_z)) \setminus \ (\cup_{i,j}\overline{W_{i,j}})$ is an open set on which an inverse is defined, and it contains $f(Z)$.

My problem is: why does it contain $f(Z)$? Certainly $W_{ij} \cap f(Z) = \emptyset$ for all $i,j$, but why should $\overline{W_{ij}} \cap f(Z) = \emptyset$ for all $i,j$? In particular, why cannot a sequence of points in $W_{ij}$ converge to a point in $f(Z)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can show that any two elements of the refined collection $\{g_i\}$ that are defined at $y$ have a nonempty open set around $y$ on which they agree:

Suppose we have two neighborhoods $V_i=f(U_i)$ and $V_j=f(U_j)$ of $y =f(z) \in f(Z)$ together with local inverses $g_i$ and $g_j$.  Then we have $$g_i(V_i) \cap g_j(V_j)=U_i \cap U_j \subset X,$$
which is an open neighborhood of $z$ in $X$. Thus the set
$$V=g_i^{-1}(U_i \cap U_j) \cap g_j^{-1}(U_i \cap U_j) $$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ in $Y$ on which $g_i$ and $g_j$ are both defined. Moreover, for $y' \in V$, we have
$$f(g_i(y'))=y'=f(g_j(y'))$$
and thus $g_i(y')=g_j(y')$ because $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: (Update: I just changed the symbols and added in the emphasis to show that the resolution is a nice fact about topological inverses.)

Comment: Why should $g(U)$ and $h(U)$ be open necessarily? For topological manifolds we can invoke invariance of domain, but why in general?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I've rolled back to my original answer and just tried to make the presentation clearer.  That previous claim that $g(U)$ and $h(U)$ are open isn't true (even for manifolds!) as stated.  My intuition was telling me that $f(g(U) \cap h(U))$ was open, but I'm not even sure if that's true or how you'd go about proving it.  Any issues with the original answer (or it's rephrasing, as it appears now)?

Comment: Looks good. But I'd quibble with what you said: I think we *can* say it for manifolds by Invariance of Domain.

Comment: Not as stated. As stated, there was no restriction barring the map from being a projection like $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: With a proper restatement, I agree that Invariance of Domain could do the trick.

Comment: But this could be semantics; I don't know for sure which version/aspect of the claim you're responding to.

Comment: I see. I thought we were assuming an inverse on an open set in the domain. My mistake.

Comment: @Kyle how do you conclude that $z\in U_{i}\cap U_{j}$, i.e., why did you assume that $g_{i}(y) = g_{j}(y) = z$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ maps $Z \subset Y$ diffeomorphically onto $f(Z) \subset Y$.

Since $df_x: T_x(X) \to T_y(y)$ is an isomorphism for each $x \in Z$, there exist open sets $x \in U_x \subset X$ and $V_x \subset Y$ such that $f$ maps $U_x$ diffeomorphically onto $V_x$ by the Inverse Function Theorem presented as Exercise 1.3.10 of Guillemin-Pollack (the compact version).

The $\{V_x\}_{x \in X}$ forms an open cover of $f(Z)$, since $f(x) \in V_x$. Now, apply Exercise 1.8.13 of Guillemin-Pollack (every open cover of $\{V_\alpha\}$ of a manifold $X$ has a locally finite refinement) to take a locally finite refinement, which we will call $V_i$, with local inverse $g_i: V_i \to X$, such that $f \circ g_i = \text{Id}_{V_i}$.

Define $W = \{y \in Y: g_i(y) = g_j(y) \text{ whenever }y \in V_i \cap V_j\}$. On $W$, it is clear we can define a global inverse $g: W \to X$ by taking $g(y) = g_i(y)$ for any $i$ such that $y \in V_i$. This is well-defined on $W$ as $g_i(y) = g_j(y)$ whenever $y \in V_i \cap V_j$.

$W$ contains $f(Z)$, as $f$ maps diffeomorphically on $f(Z)$, so $g_i(y) = g_j(y) = f^{-1}(y)$ for any $y \in Z$. Now fix a $f(x) \in f(Z)$. We wish to show that $W$ contains an open neighborhood of $f(x)$. By the property that $\{V_i\}$ is a locally finite cover of $f(Z)$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ that intersects only finitely many of the $V_i$ – by reindexing them, if necessary, call them $V_1, \dots, V_k$.

Then $\widetilde{V} = V \cap V_1 \cap \dots \cap V_k$ is a finite intersection of open sets that contain $f(x)$, so $\widetilde{V}$ is an open neighborhood of $f(x)$. Moreover, on $\widetilde{V}$ each $g_i$ is a local diffeomorphism with $g(\widetilde{V}) \subset U_i \ni x$. Hence, on $\widetilde{V}$, the $g_i$ all agree, so $\widetilde{V} \subset W$. So we are done.

Comment: I am convinced that the $g_i$ must agree on $\cap_i g_i^{-1}(\cap_i g_i(V_i))$, as @squirrel says, but I am not convinced that the $g_i$ agree on $\tilde{V}$. If I'm mistaken, could you clarify this point, perhaps? I.e. I am not convinced by your last sentence "Hence, on $\tilde{V}$...". $f$ is of course not assumed injective, so why could it not be that local diffeomorphisms defined on the same open set, and which are sections of $f$, and which share a point in their image, nevertheless disagree somewhere?

Comment: As a counterexample, take the neighborhood $(-.1, .1) \cup (\pi - .1, \pi + .1)$ on the circle, taken to either $(-.1, .1) \cup (\pi - .1, \pi + .1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $(-.1, .1) \cup (3\pi - .1, \pi + .1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. They are both sections of the covering map, both defined on the same open set, both local diffeomorphisms, share a point in their image, and yet do not agree everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Eric is correct--the answer by user149792 is insufficient. Instead, we can modify his/her arguments easily by taking the $V_i$'s that contain the point $y$. Then, the local finiteness ensures there are only a finite number of $V_i$'s. Then, since the intersection of the images $U_i$'s ($g_i(V_i)=U_i$) is nonempty, by the injectivity of $f$, we conclude that all $g_i$ must agree on the intersection $\cap_i V_i$.